# readr: the read_delim function throws error "embedded nul in string: '\0'"

Tags: r, readr

I am using the `readr` library and `read_delim` function in `R`. I have a big file it has null spaces, so I run the function like this:

```
read_delim(paste0(dir,name,".txt"),delim="\t",
col_types=paste0(c(rep("c",17),rep("_",10),rep("c",2),rep("_",2),rep("c",1),rep("_",28),rep("c",1),rep("c",3),rep("c",12),rep("_",3),rep("c",1),rep("_",4),rep("c",21)),collapse=""),escape_backslash=T,na="NA",quote="'\"",n_max=6,progress=interactive())
```

This code throws the following error:

> Error in read_tokens(ds, tokenizer, col_types, col_names, n_max =
>   n_max,  :    embedded nul in string: '\0'

I tried to change "quote" parameter for quote="":

```
read_delim(paste0(dir,name,".txt"),delim="\t",
col_types=paste0(c(rep("c",17),rep("_",10),rep("c",2),rep("_",2),rep("c",1),rep("_",28),rep("c",1),rep("c",3),rep("c",12),rep("_",3),rep("c",1),rep("_",4),rep("c",21)),collapse=""),escape_backslash=T,na="NA",quote="",n_max=6,progress=interactive())
```

This function reads my file but the columns mismatched outputting incorrectly.

How can I correct this error?

Comment: You don't need to inform `col_types` because they will be imputed from the first 30 rows on the input file. It's hard to know if this is the problem without a reproducible example, but try the same code without  `col_types`. I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but `read_tsv` is appropriate for tab delimited files.